# Сравнить два массива и удалить дубликат javasript

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть два массива которые приходят с сервера. у них есть дубликаты
нужно сравнить значения 1 со 2 и сделать 3 масив без дубликатов оставив значения первого + добавить значения второго

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пытаюсь сделать следующее: но возвращает только первый массив

```
positiveArr = positiveArr.filter(function(val) {
        return positiveArr2.indexOf(val) == -1;
      });
```

Comment: _масив без дубликатов оставив значения первого_ - _но возвращает только первый массив_ - не вижу противоречий

Comment: Мне нужно если в 1 и 2 массиве присутствует одинаковая запись. оставить запись первого и добавить значения 2 в массив

Comment: Тогда ты должен правильно писать то, что хочешь получить, сейчас ты получаешь именно то, о чем написал

Comment: т.е по итогу должны быть значения из первого массива + значения из второго. без дубликатов

Comment: а если в первом были дубликаты? например: `[1, 1, 1]`, объединять с `[1,2,3]` какой должен быть результат?

Comment: в первом не будет дубликатов